# DB2 query optimization; LIKE alternative

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, sql-like

I'm looking to do a wildcard search but I'm noticing some performance degradation on some particular strings(those that initially return a large number filtering down to few).

```
SELECT       tbl_1.KEY
           , tbl_1.USERID
           , tbl_1.DOMAIN 
           , tbl_2.*
           , tbl_3.*
           , tbl_4.*


FROM       , tbl_1 
           , tbl_2                 
           , tbl_3                    
           , tbl_4   

WHERE        tbl_1.KEY                   =      tbl_2.KEY
AND          tbl_1.KEY                   =      tbl_3.KEY
AND          tbl_1.KEY                   =      tbl_4.KEY 
AND          UPPER(tbl_1.USERID)         LIKE   'STRING%' 
AND          UPPER(tbl_1.DOMAIN)         LIKE   'STRING%' 
AND          tbl_3.CRIT1                 =      ''  
AND          tbl_3.CRIT2                 IN     ('')
AND          tbl_4.CRIT3                 =      ''
```

Essentially I'm returning an individual profile based on email address and domain wildcards then filtering. There's an Index on the tbl_1 consisting of the KEY, USERID, and DOMAIN. I'm trying to avoid a table scan and use only the Index'd fields. DB2 LIKE does not seem to be Index Only supported.

Comment: Edit your question, and paste in the execution plan. As a general rule, any current dbms *can* use an index when you don't lead with a wildcard. The query optimizer might choose *not* to use the index, though.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I'll have to look in to that as I'm not that familiar with it; I'm just attempting to write the query. I am currently not leading with a wildcard.

Comment: I believe DB2 is smart enough to optimize `LIKE` statements without leading wildcards to simple comparisons (essentially ending the check early), like `SUBSTR`.  The `UPPER` is most likely part of the problem.  Oh, it shouldn't effect your runtime any, but stop using the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) and explicitly list your joins (so, `(INNER) JOIN tbl_2 ON ...` etc).  Note that the implicit syntax has problems with attempting outer (optional) joins.

Answer (score 1):

The UPPER() may be the problem...Not sure about DB2 LUW but at least in DB2 for IBM i it would be.  The "right" way to do a case insensitive search is with a case insensitive collating sequence or a derived index.

A derived index:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON MYTABLE (UPPER(USERID))
```

On DB2 for IBM i, you can use a case insensitive collating sequence by setting

```
SET OPTION SRTSEQ = *LANGIDSHR
```

Note, you have to have *LANGIDSHR set when you issue the `CREATE INDEX myindex ON MYTABLE (USERID)` and when you are doing the `SELECT`.

Comment: I believe this is the case.

Comment: In that case, you can add an extra generated column for the userid and domain with the upper values, and then put them in an index.

Comment: @crownedzero - Setting the `SRTSEQ` is going to be a global setting for what is essentially a "local" problem (there are potentially still times you want to sort with case sensitivity, never mind the fact that non-ASCII characters may behave strangely).  Creating derived indices (or potentially just storing those two columns in a "normalized" form) is probably the better option.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse...SRTSEQ is connection dependent on DB2 for IBM i...and it doesn't appear that DB2 LUW offers similar functionality.